# Flutter: how to get value from sharedpreferences? when i debug, the value is Instance of 'Future<String>'

Tags: flutter

i entered data using

```
Future<bool> saveSession() async{
    final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.setString('test', 'Some Data');
  }
```

and get data using

```
Future<String> readSession() async{
    final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.getString('test');
  }
```

when i try to debug it using

print(readSession()); // value is Instance of 'Future'

i dont know why ??

result is Instance of 'Future'

Comment: Take a read of this https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures basically your `String` is inside of a class called `Future`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the string value you need to resolve the `Future` object first. There are basically two ways to achieve that:

## 1

```
print(await readSession());
```

## 2

```
readSession().then((v) => print(v));
```

You can read more about asynchronous operations in official docs - https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures